# How do you compare classes that contain `Closure`?

Tags: php, php-closures

So, how do you compare classes that contain `Closure` ? It looks like you can't.

```
class a {
    protected $whatever;
    function __construct() {    
        $this->whatever = function() {};
    }
}

$b = new a();
$c = new a();

var_dump( $b == $c );   //false
```

Comment: So is it based on the class?  So if you did `$c->var = 1;` should they still be `==` or not?

Comment: The easiest may be a custom comparison method: `$b->isEqual($c)`, in which you compare everything that matters for equality and ignore incomparable values.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) closures straight on, but you can do a workaround, since `serialize()` invokes [`__sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) when it's serializing objects, so it gives the object to option to clean things up! This what we're doing here:

```
class a {

    protected $whatever;

    function __construct() {    
        $this->whatever = function() {};
    }

    public function __sleep() {
        $r = [];
        foreach ($this as $k => $v){
            if (!is_array($v) && !is_string($v) && is_callable($v))
                continue;
            $r[] = $k;
        }
        return $r;
    }

}
```

So now you can use `serialize()` with `md5()` to compare your objects like this:

```
var_dump(md5(serialize($b)) === md5(serialize($c)));
```

output:

```
bool(true)
```

Comment: Yeah, it will work for this specific case. But if you redefine whatever they would still be equal. See question update.

Comment: @user2398964 As I said in the answer it's a workaround that you are still able to serialize an object even if it has a closure in it! By simply removing them. But I don't think there is currently a way how you can compare 2 objects with closures in it